# onsen-UIでの背景の変更

Tags: javascript, onsen-ui, css

onsen-UIでのCSSで

```
.page__background {
  background:url('../images/title_img.jpg') no-repeat;
  background-size: auto 80%;
  background-position: center;
}
```

このように背景を設定しているのですが、
この背景画像を変更するには、どのようなJavascriptを作成すればよいのでしょうか?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

話を簡潔にするためにjQueryを導入している前提で書きます。

### styleを直接書き換える方法

DOMのプロパティを直接書き換える方法です。urlは絶対パスにするか、htmlからの相対パスを指定してください。

```
$('.page__background').css('backgroundImage', 'url("pass/to/image")');
```

---

### クラスを付与する方法

背景画像差し替え用のスタイル定義を用意し、JavaScriptではクラスの付与のみを行う方法です。近年はDOMを直接書き換えることはあまり推奨されませんので、こちらの方法をおすすめしておきます。

```css
.page__background {
  background:url('../images/title_img.jpg') no-repeat;
  background-size: auto 80%;
  background-position: center;
}
.page__background--bg2 {
  background-image:url('pass/to/image');
}
```

```js
$('.page__background').addClass('page__background--bg2');
```